# Extracting Directions , Bus Gps Data

Tags: python, geolocation, geospatial, data-analysis

I am studying Transportation Engineering but I have a problem in a GPS data

I have a large dataset of a Bus Rapid Transit Sytem GPS data .

Data itself contains several columns which are:

- `BuslocationID` --> An ID number generated by the signal count that has been sent from the bus
- `DoorID` --> A unique ID for each bus
- `Timeofthesignalsent` --> Time of the each signal that has been sent from the bus
- `Space` -- > The taken road since the beginning of the current voyage
- `Speed` -- > Speed that has been calculated by the gps device
- `Timeofthesignalsent` --> Recive time of the each signal that has been sent by the busses.

My problem is the data does not contain a column for a direction of the bus is taking.

The entire system works as a 2x1 lane right of way.

Which is two directions and one line eachway.

I need a way to categorize which direction is the buses are taking and append it as a column to the data.

After this I am going to create a time-space diagram for each direction for the entire system to detect recurrent bottlenecks.

I am open to suggestions for creation of direction column.

Ps: I am using `Python 3.7.1` in all of my coding.

What I had in mind is that , my route is changing linearly in the lateral direction so I can just use longtitudes. So there is a five main bus stops(in total 44)  in my route and their longtitudes is like this :

```
1 st stop --> 28.624860


2 nd stop --> 28.725766


3 rd stop --> 28.910323


4 th stop --> 29.012753


5 th stop --> 29.035870
```

As you can see the longtitudes changes can solve this but there is one problem.There are many data points in my dataset where the consecutive longtitudes does not change and which means the bus is currently stopping. So if the consecutive data is not changing there is no way of knowing which way it is going.
Here is what I did so far :

```
for i in range(0,len(M3042)-1,2):
    #M3042[i],M3042[i+1]
    if float(M3042[i][3])-float(M3042[i+1][3]) < 0:
        M3042[i][8]=1
        M3042[i+1][8]=1
    if float(M3042[i][3])-float(M3042[i+1][3]) > 0 :
        M3042[i][8]=0
        M3042[i+1][8]=0
```

M3042 --> type is Numpy Array , which is also the doorid from my dataset

the 3 rd column is the longtitude column.
(and the "1" from the M3042[i][8]=1 , means since this is a 2 way system , I am just going to categorize the direction by 0 and 1 )

Thanks for the help

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you show some code of your attempts on the problem?

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply , I updated my post.